# Unable to access Google Sheet API through proxy

Tags: python, pycharm, google-sheets-api, http-proxy

Accessing Google SpreadSheet through Google Sheet API acquires TimeoutError Exception.

When I try making use of python to connect Google Sheet API,  I find the article about entire process.
[Link](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-the-google-sheets-api-with-python)
Finally I use this code to read the title of my sheets storing the cloud drive,

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

spreadsheet_id = "xxx"

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("key.json", scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"])
service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=credentials)

request = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=[], includeGridData=False)
sheet_props = request.execute()

print(sheet_props["properties"]["title"])
```

According I can't access Google directly, I set up a proxy through clash, and Configuring it in Pycharm
[Pycharm configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFMzw.png)

Then I write code to connect Google (Use the module requests), and status code is 200
[Test connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LEcZ.png)

But the first code still not working, and return TimeoutError Exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\security\GoogleDork\start.py", line 10, in <module>
    sheet_props = request.execute()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\security\GoogleDork\venv\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\security\GoogleDork\venv\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 923, in execute
    resp, content = _retry_request(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\security\GoogleDork\venv\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 222, in _retry_request
    raise exception
  File "D:\security\GoogleDork\venv\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 191, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\security\GoogleDork\venv\Lib\site-packages\google_auth_httplib2.py", line 209, in request
    self.credentials.before_request(self._request, method, uri, request_headers)
  File "D:\security\GoogleDork\venv\Lib\site-packages\google\auth\credentials.py", line 175, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "D:\security\GoogleDork\venv\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\service_account.py", line 449, in refresh
    access_token, expiry, _ = _client.jwt_grant(
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\security\GoogleDork\venv\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 308, in jwt_grant
    response_data = _token_endpoint_request(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\security\GoogleDork\venv\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 268, in _token_endpoint_request
    response_status_ok, response_data, retryable_error = _token_endpoint_request_no_throw(
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\security\GoogleDork\venv\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 215, in _token_endpoint_request_no_throw
    request_succeeded, response_data, retryable_error = _perform_request()
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\security\GoogleDork\venv\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 191, in _perform_request
    response = request(
               ^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\security\GoogleDork\venv\Lib\site-packages\google_auth_httplib2.py", line 119, in __call__
    response, data = self.http.request(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\security\GoogleDork\venv\Lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1724, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\security\GoogleDork\venv\Lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1444, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\security\GoogleDork\venv\Lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1366, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "D:\security\GoogleDork\venv\Lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1156, in connect
    sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]
```

I hope I can get help here